# How to increase width of particular  EditText in Table Raw (Table layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am using Table Layout.

Here i have three `EditText's` with same `width ="200dp"`.

But i want to increase the size of 3rd `EditText`.

I made its `width="wrap_content"` but all other EditText also getting "`wrap_content`"

How can i increase the `width` of 3rd `EditText` with out affecting other `EditText's`.

This code for 3rd EditText:-

```
 <TableRow 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="left" 
                android:id="@+id/addl" 
                android:text="Address" 
                />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="right" 
                android:id="@+id/colon"
                            android:text=":" />

            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="250dp" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
                android:id="@+id/et"
                android:singleLine="true"/>            
        </TableRow>
```

[image]
Now i want to increase `width` of Address `EditText` only

Comment: use android:layout_weight attribute for this purpose..

Comment: weight will not work on this..

Answer (score 4):

i think you can achieve this by `layout_weight` parameter of `EditText`s like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#909090"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student ID"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**EDIT**

This is the outcome

[image]

Comment: layout:weight is not working....TextView and edittext is out of app format. for that particular row...i need to see other two rows also.

Comment: @MontySharma i uploaded an outcome image. what is your exact problem now. Can you upload a picture/screenshot that shows your problem ? you can use http://imgur.com/ to upload images till SO allows you to upload images

Comment: @MontySharma can you please elaborate your issue

Comment: I have posted my image ..now you can get the problem easily

Comment: ok.. i just updated the XML to suit your need and you can see the outcome of this xml in the uploaded screenshot

Comment: @MontySharma were you able to test this ?

Comment: what is the diffrence in your Ui and my Ui....same thing..only i want to increase the width of Address EditText..if i increase weight of edittext.it ll affect Textview also..

Comment: @MontySharma as you can see in the screenshot (which i uploaded), almost all width of the screen is occupied by views. ie, the width of `Address` field cannot increased further. What you can try is apply a `layout_marginRight` property to `Name` & `Class` `TableRow`s. Now you get a feeling that `Address` field has a `increased` width.

Comment: @MontySharma If you can upload a picture, may be created from mspaint or any tool, so that i will get a better picture

Answer (score 0):

put the property `android:stretchColumns="2"` in `TableLayout`

```
<TableLayout android:stretchColumns="2" ... > .... </TableLayout>
```

Comment: u also need to change EditText's width to match_parent `<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" `